# Fetch all rows related to user

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to create a json object with data from two tables.

**Table 1 holds user information**
id
name
username
email

**Table 2 holds messages to the users** 
id
f_id
message
date

So far so good. I have managed to do this with LEFT JOIN

```
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN messages ON user.id = messages.f_id 


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $messages[] = array(
        'users' => array(
                        'Id' => $data['id'],
                        'Name' => $data['name'],
                        'Username' => $data['username'],
                        'Email' => $data['email'],

        ),
        'messages' => array(
                        'f_id' => $data['f_id'],
                        'message' => $data['message'],
                        'date' => $data['date'],
        );
        );

    }
```

but the issue/challenge is that it only returns one row from messages table even if there multiple rows related to the user.

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
                'user' => array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'name' => John Doe,
                        'username' => Johndoe,
                        'email' => johndoe@mail.com,
        ),
        'messages' => array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'f_id' => 1,
                        'message' => 'Just a test',
                        'date' => 14-08-2014,

                        'id' => 2,
                        'f_id' => 1,
                        'message' => 'Just a test 1',
                        'date' => 12-08-2014,
        );
```

How can I achieve this?
Do I need to run a while in while?

Comment: The problem is not in your SQL but in your PHP code. Please post the relevent section.

Comment: So many fastest gun in the west replies! Many of them just echoing the exact same query as given in the question!

Comment: @Rorabih You want to merge user details and messages in query result?

Comment: @RahulVyas Yes correct - I did achieve merging them together with a LEFT JOIN but the issue is that the messages table only outputs one row. I would like to know how to run a "while" within the array so I get the same output as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1) Query only the users, and then iterate over them and query the messages for each user. That means that you will query the database N+1 times, where N is the number of users.

2) Query the *messages* joined with the users (and not the opposite), which will result with a lot of "unused" data, but a single query.

Comment: sorry but using a query inside a loop definitely isn't the way to go.

Comment: I agree, but that is still an option, that is why I presented both options. The order of them has not meaning.

Comment: I am not into putting queries inside my loop. I had some performance issues related to a another project by doing it that way. Thank you anyway @RonDadon

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    user.id AS user_id, user.name, user.email, user.username,
    messages.id AS message_id, messages.f_id, messages.message, messages.date 
FROM user, messages 
LEFT JOIN messages ON user.id = messages.f_id
```

Note that an alias was needed for `user.id` and `messages.id` as both column names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user Right JOIN messages ON user.id = messages.f_id
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = messages.f_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that :

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = messages.f_id
```

It will get all messages with users but if a user has no messages, you'll not be able to get it with this kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that when you're running the query on the users table, it will use the primary key of that table to ensure that there's no "duplicate" data (as it should). You have two options here:

## Query Users, Query Messages [Not Recommended]

This might be a little slow since you'll be querying the database many times. You could do something like

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

then later iterate over the users result and run a query on messages

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE f_id = <user_id>;
```

**What's the issue with this?** The more users you have, the more *wasteful* this is, and also the slower your site will perform. Not recommended.

## Query messages, join users [Recommended]

Run this query on messages, rather than users. It will use the primary key of the messages table (which will be id) to determine what is a duplicate or not.

```
SELECT * FROM messages LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = messages.f_id;
```

This is much more efficient because it's using one query to grab all the data you need and it should need a little tweaking maybe as your site grows.

Comment: Using this returns redundant/duplicate data (1 row - 2 times) I only need messages table to output all rows related to the users table WHERE users.id = messages.f_id; in an array as described in my question.

Comment: You can't expect SQL to format the data for you - you'll need to do some stuff with PHP to get the exact output that you have described. What PHP code are you using currently?

Comment: === Edit === It outputs only users which has a message related - and it is shown as two seperate objects. Can messages be listed inside the array as described in my question?

Comment: Not with the single query. Again, you'll need to tell PHP to construct the array. You could do the top option, again, not recommended but then you'll get all users and messages as separate objects, which you can use to construct the data the way you want it.

Comment: Which is done by doing this: $sql = "SELECT * ".
 "FROM messages LEFT JOIN users ".
 "ON users.id = messages.f_id";
 
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  
  $messages[] = array(
   'users' => array(
       'Id' => $data['id'],
       'Name' => $data['name'],
       'Username' => $data['username'],
       'Email' => $data['email'],

   ),
   'messages' => array(
       'f_id' => $data['f_id'],
       'message' => $data['message'],
       'date' => $data['date'],
   );
   );
  
  }

Comment: Could you instead update your question? I'm finding it hard to read in the comments

Comment: Added to question.